# ASP.NET MVC Equivalent to Response.Redirect Click Event

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an html form in a view that needs to be reset from time to time.  Problem is, fields enable/disable based on input.  Therefore, the only way to truly reset the form is to reload the view (I would prefer that the entire page is reloaded).  Due to several scenarios, simply refreshing does not work.  I need the equivalent to Response.Redirect() and have the view redirect to itself...  Haven't been able to find a good solution yet.

I have tried:

- Adding an ActionResult in the controller that

  ```
  public ActionResult ResetNoteReport()
  {
      return RedirectToAction("NoteReport");
  }
  ```
- Setting a click event on the button itself that

  ```
  onclick="window.location.href('<%= Url.Action("NoteReport")%>');"
  ```
- Removing input and setting values to null or "" via JQuery...

Among plenty of other stabs...

Comment: Could you provide some more information as to how some of your past attempts were inadequate?  And perhaps explain why simply refreshing does not work?

Comment: use jQuery. More consistent and integrated into ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, my attempts at using window.location.href() was buggy earlier and would not reload the page. I don't know what was wrong with it before, but the following works perfectly fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function reload() {
        window.location.href = "<%=Url.Action("NoteReport") %>";
    };
</script>

<%= Html.Button("reset", "Reset", HtmlButtonType.Button, "reload()") %>
```

Comment: try window.location.reload() if all you want is the current location reloaded.

Comment: window.location.replace(window.location.href)  should work, but will remove the original entry in the browser history.

Answer (score 0):

just an aside but rather than change the page could you not use one of the jquery form utilities to clear the form?

Comment: I was getting close with that, but our application is for a base of roughly 300 users and we are more concerned about clean code so long as we aren't being ridiculous with server calls.  Using window.location.href required 1 line where using JQuery to clear the ugly form I'm dealing with would have taken a few at the least...

Answer (score 0):

> Problem is, fields enable/disable based on input.

That is exactly one situation when MVC is not good to go with. WebForms perform much better in such scenarios.

Comment: Agreed.  As of now, I miss webforms quite a bit.  However, the more I work with MVC and understand it, the more I see the benefits.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= Html.Button("reset", "Reset", HtmlButtonType.Button, "window.location.reload()") %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried this, but it doesn't work when I attempt to submit the form with bad data.  The server validation returns the form with the bad data persisted and info as to why the submission failed.  After clicking the Reset button you suggested above, the form does not reload to it's original state.

Comment: Gotcha, realized this on retrospect, since it's just refreshing the last request, not forcing to the same url as a get...

Comment: Is there a new release of MVC that I don't know of? I installed the framework when NerdDinner came out and Html.Button is not available (unresolved symbol).